# Wordpress Permalinks Overriding .htaccess https and force slash

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am wanting to use the following .htaccess however it works to a point but for me to access the sub pages I have to reset my permalinks and there for this section gets reset.

It seems in Wordpress currently there is only plugins to do one or another - not both of my goals.

**Goals:**

1. To force HTTP:// to HTTPS://
2. Include a trailing `/` at the end of the url

**.htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-content\/cache\/(all|wpfc-mobile-cache)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    RewriteBase /subFolder/ 
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /subFolder/index.php [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

[WordPress makes this block in your `.htaccess` file. Note the first and last line](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess) (I added "subfolder/" to fit your example):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /subfolder/
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /subfolder/index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

WordPress in theory shouldn't be overridding anything outside of the `# Begin / #End` lines. So you can place your extra code above or below it.

That being said, WordPress adds a trailing slash by default when using PostName/pretty permalinks so I don't think you'd need anything extra. And generally if you set the Site URL to have https, all generated links will be over https as well, with the notable exception of existing media/links in the content editor. For those, add this below the `#End WordPress` above (switch example.com to your domain):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, Sorry I have been busy with your response it worked fine however of course it would just redirect it to https://domain.co.nz however if I changed it to domain\.co.nz and https://domain.co.nz/subFolder/$1 it does not work